# Selecting top 5 rows with distinct single column value

Tags: hive, hiveql, hdp

I am trying to pull the top five states with the highest measurements related to a specific measureid. My issue is that I am trying to pull DISTINCT states with the highest measurements.

My query:

```
select distinct measureid, reportyear, statename, max(value)
from air_quality
where measureid = 87
and reportyear >= 2008
and reportyear <= 2013
group by measureid, reportyear, statename, value
limit 5
```

I expect the output with DISTINCT statenames, i.e., I don't want one repeated. If California has the highest for one year, it will not be repeated again.

Currently it displays as "... California, 22 ; ... California, 22 ; ... California, 19 ; ... Arizona, 18 ; ... California, 18"

Comment: share your schema and some sample data, also you are doing DISTINCT measureid not DISTINCT statename

Comment: @PabloPazos The dataset can be found on https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/air-quality-measures-on-the-national-environmental-health-tracking-network via the csv file.

Comment: you should publish a complete question without external references, also check where you put the distinct, should be in the statename because that is what you want.

Comment: Please provide input data example (including all columns in the query) and desired result